# Edit text in File

Tags: c++, qt

In the program records various information and would like to edit two in one file, the user will type in a lineEdit and will swap in the file

My code:

```
QString valor = ui->edtRValor->text();
QDate dateIn = ui->dateRInicial->date();
QString dataInicio = dateIn.toString();
QDate dateFi = ui->dateRFim->date();
QString FimDate = dateFi.toString();

 QFile arch("C:\\Users\\Caio\\Documents\\cadastrarQuarto.txt");
     if(!sr.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
             return;
  QTextStream out(&arch);
```

How do I get the value typed and swap with a value that is written in the file?

My file:

```
231-1º-40-sáb jan 1 2000-qua jan 5 2000-160-2
441-4º-40-sáb jan 1 2020-qua jan 5 2200-190-8
```

Comment: your data is just written in the file with is "hard" to manipulate later (as you can see)... my suggestion is to use some format that defines the info you have in the file... newest versions of QT support JSON objects... please take a look at that...

Answer (score 0):

and if you did ?

```
QString dataInicio = dateIn.toString("dd.MM.yyyy");

QString FimDate = dateFi.toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

for date view format.